# Java arrayList vs. C++ vector

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the C++ version of Java's ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971049/whats-the-c-version-of-javas-arraylist)

I was reading a book called "Cracking the Coding Interview" and most (all?) of the code is in Java and arrayList is used a lot. During an interview, would using a vector instead of arrayList be acceptable if the language is C++? I'm asking because I haven't seen even one example of C++ code for similar questions using a vector but I'm not sure if there's a significant difference or not.

And is there also an equivalent in C?

Comment: C has no vector implementation natively. Chained lists are what is easiest to implement

Comment: You might want to read a book on the STL before you start preparing to interview for C++ jobs.

Comment: Also, the C standard library doesn't really implement general purpose data structures. You can get them from third-party libraries like [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-data-types.html)

Comment: @Inerdial: Better still, you might want to read a [modern C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242). The STL has been obsolete for more than a decade.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is two-fold: Firstly, you cannot compare utility classes between C++ and Java like that - different languages come with different cultures, naming conventions etc. If there was a Vector class in a C++ library, there's no connection whatsoever to any Vector class in Java, except for the name.

Secondly, the Vector class in Java is in practice deprecated, and I would discourage you from using it. In fact, forget about it :) The combination of List and ArrayList is the way to go. Use interfaces where you can, say:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

Example deliberately missing generic typing.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring synchronization, the main difference between Vector and ArrayList is that Vector is a resizable array (similar to a C++ STL Vector) and ArrayList is a List that happens to be backed by an array.

[arraylist-vs-vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300519/arraylist-vs-vectors-in-java-if-thread-safety-isnt-a-concern)

In the back end, they are both arrays with functions on top to assist the programmer. Now, how different are they fundamentally?

check here :
 http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/l6o65/arraylist_java_vs_vectors_c/