# Java ArrayList in C++

Tags: java, c++

In Java I can do

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("my name");
```

How would I do the same in C++?

Comment: People, stop downvoting. It discourages programmers coming from other languages to learn C++. There is nothing wrong in the question.

Comment: I wonder what thought process, if any, went into that downvote.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `std::vector` and `std::string`:

```
#include <vector>  //for std::vector
#include <string>  //for std::string

std::vector<std::string> data;
data.push_back("my name");
```

Note that in C++, you don't need to use `new` everytime you create an object.  The object `data` is default initialized by calling the default constructor of `std::vector`. So the above code is fine.

In C++, the moto is : **Avoid `new` as much as possible**.

If you know the size already at compile time and the array doesn't need to grow, then you can use `std::array`:

```
#include <array> //for std::array

std::array<std::string, N> data; //N is compile-time constant
data[i] = "my name"; //for i >=0 and i < N
```

Read the documentation for more details:

- [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/string)
- [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

---

C++ Standard library has many containers. Depending on situation you have to choose one which best suits your purpose. It is not possible for me to talk about each of them. But here is the chart that helps a lot ([source](http://linuxsoftware.co.nz/cppcontainers.html)):

[image]

Comment: Won't you need to initialize the class first?

Comment: @Sheeo: Huh?  The vector is already initialised.

Comment: I don't see a call to the constructor...

Comment: @Sheeo: It is default initialized, the default constructor is called auotmatically.

Answer (score 0):

All combined in one line
vector myVec(1,"hello");